What is this comedy about a TV reporter doing a live broadcast at a waterfall?
This is a comedy about a middle-aged man who tries different jobs but keep being fired because of his strange personality:
In one sequence, he was being a TV reporter. He was on a boat with the
British Queen that was about to visit a waterfall. His task was to
 broadcast live.
When the picture is live, he kept silent like he was
waiting for the signal to begin, but other TV crew members kept
whispering to him that they are already on-air. 
The people in the broadcast room in the TV station suspects a technical problem, and the supervisor asks a technician to check if the audio is working, which he replies "it is working perfectly".
After a long wait, finally he begins talking, but he said something which was entirely out of place. The people in the broadcast room quickly cut the feed and switched to another channel.
I watched this on TV and didn't finish the whole movie, this is the only excerpt I remember. I think the entire sequence lasts somewhere between 5~10 minutes. It is definitely released before 2010. Which movie is this?

The movie you are looking for is Bruce Almighty.
Bruce is a local TV report in Buffalo who feels like the rest of the world is to blame for him not being where he wants to be in his life. He's hoping for a major promotion to the news desk, but just as he's about to do a live broadcast from below Niagara Falls he learns that his rival has been promoted instead and goes into a meltdown just as they switch the broadcast to his location.
The specific scene:



